# MicrosoftAccessにSQLServerからリンクテーブルを張り、それをクエリで計算しようとするとオーバーフローする

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

MicrosoftAccessにSQLServerからリンクを張ったテーブルを
SQLで計算して表示しようとすると、オーバーフローを起こして
エラーになってしまいます。

リンクを張らずにローカルテーブルの時は普通に計算できていたのですが、
リンクにするとエラーになってしまいます。

下記が使用しているSQLです。

```
SELECT [categoly],SUM(CLNG(([幅]*[高]*[長]*[個数]*[価格]) / 1000000000)) AS [合計] FROM ([M_材料] WHERE [id] = 187 GROUP BY [categoly]
```

体積をmmで出ているデータの為か、かなり大きい数字になってしまうようで、どうすればいいか解らずにいます。

解決策をお願いできますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: テーブル定義と、正確なエラーメッセージをお願いします。あとSQL Serverのバージョンもできれば

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問内容に図を追加しました。SQLServerは2019年度版です。categolyはバイト型ですが、他はすべて長整数型です。

Comment: SQL Server側のテーブル定義もお願いします。あえてCLNGしている理由はありますか？

Comment: もしかしたらこれらが関係しているのかも？ [SQL Serverにリンク接続しているテーブルを開くと#Deletedと表示される](https://asbepartners.com/deleted/), [大きい数値データ型を使用する](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/5b623f6e-641d-4e97-8bdf-b77bae076f70) `既定では、大きい数値データ型は、リンクとインポートの操作に対して有効ではありません。`

Comment: エラーメッセージから考えて、おそらく単にint型でオーバーフローしているだけだと思いますよ。/1000000000を/1000000000.0とかにすると動いたりしませんかね

Comment: 『.0』を追加するだけでは変わりませんでした。ちなみにCLNGは、SUMを行う直前で小数の端数がある場合、合計額が変わってしまうので、SUMの直前に小数を切り捨てています。

Answer (score 0):

どうやってSQLを発行しようとしているのかわかりませんが、とりあえず計算式を

```
[幅] / 1000000000.0 *[高]*[長]*[個数]*[価格]
```

のようにすれば動くかと思います。
ただし、CLNGしているのでこの計算式がVBAのLongの範囲内に収まることが前提ですが。
エラーの原因は、SQL Serverではint型同士の演算はint型になるからです。
小数点付きのリテラルはdecimal(numeric)型とみなされるので、int型を超える範囲でも計算できるようになります。

あとCLNGは切り捨てではなくて、いわゆる銀行丸めという丸めを行います。
余談ですが、CLNGはVBAの関数なので、大量データを処理するとパフォーマンスが出ない可能性が高いですよ。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。まだ確認作業に移れていないので確認はできませんが、確認出来たらまた書き込みいたします。ご返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。